# Which Account is Picked to Run SQL Server Job When Run As is Empty

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, permissions, file-permissions, sql-agent-job

I have a job agent to execute multiple steps.  Each step's Run As is empty.  Does that mean the job will run as job owner's account or the local system account?

Comment: See [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/setting-up-your-sql-server-agent-correctly/) `By default, SQL Server Agent executes job steps under the SQL Server Agent service account irrespective of job ownership, or under the context of a proxy account.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be the account associated to the SQL Server Agent service, not the one associated to the job owner. It can be the local system account, if that is the one associated to the SQL Server Agent; but best practice is for the SQL Server Agent to run with its own account.